# Using HitTest function in touch and mouse clicks at the same time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, hittest, onmouseclick

Can anyone tell me why I get this error when writing this code?

```
Debug.Log(pauseIcon.GetComponent<GUITexture>().guiTexture.HitTest(Input.touches[0].position)+pauseIcon.GetComponent<GUITexture>().guiTexture.HitTest(Input.mousePosition) );



error : IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
OnlineBall.Update () (at Assets/OnlineBall.cs:180)
```

if I delete:

```
pauseIcon.GetComponent<GUITexture>().guiTexture.HitTest(Input.touches[0].position)
```

or

```
pauseIcon.GetComponent<GUITexture>().guiTexture.HitTest(Input.mousePosition)
```

I will not get any error. Why can't I use both of them at the same time?

Comment: The error is pretty explanatory, your index is out of range.  Before that first debug statement have you checked that `Input.touchCount > 0`?  If not, `Input.touches[0]` will give you that error if there aren't any touches currently.

Comment: i put Input.touchCount > 0 before debug but the error is happening again. 

 if(Input.touchCount > 0)  pauseIcon.GetComponent<GUITexture>().guiTexture.HitTest(Input.touches[0].position);

Comment: Are you really getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException`? Is this really the code your script is using? Your code wouldn't even compile, because you can't use the operator `+` for two `booleans`.

Comment: i have a string too and it compiles successfully  :    `Debug.Log("here"+pauseIcon.GetComponent<GUITexture>().guiTexture.HitTest(Input.touches[0].position)+pauseIcon.GetComponent<GUITexture>().guiTexture.HitTest(Input.mousePosition) );`

Comment: With the check that Jerdak mentioned, this error should not be possible. There must be a missing curly bracket or a similar simple mistake. Please add the whole `Update()` method to your question, including the added check, if you still can't find a solution by yourself.

Comment: You have to post more code (entire `Update()` method) but I suspect the problem is that you call `touches[0]` without validating the `touchCount`.  To be clear, I mean that you need to test `touchCount` before *any* line that explicitly calls `touches[0]` or do something like `if(Input.touchCount>0)return;` to break out of `Update` if no touches occurred last frame.